# DeprecationWarning: `np.bool`

Tags: python, numpy, boolean

I am new to Python using Spyder. I have written the following code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
os.environ["CDF_LIB"] = "D:\Anaconda\Lib"
from spacepy import pycdf

cdf = pycdf.CDF('Sample.cdf')
print(cdf)  # Print the titles of the CDF file
Diff_en=cdf['diff'][:]
```

For some reason I keep getting the following error and I'm not sure why (I don't know what bool is). Any help is appreciated:

```
Diff_en=cdf['diff'][:]
D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spacepy\pycdf\__init__.py:3957: DeprecationWarning: `np.bool` is a deprecated alias for the builtin `bool`. To silence this warning, use `bool` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.bool_` here.
Deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
```

Comment: This is a problem with Spacepy, not your code.

Comment: It seems you have an old version of spacepy. They fixed this deprecation warning in their Github code on 1 March 2021 (they stopped using `numpy.bool` and now just use `bool` instead).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a harmless warning. If you can live with it, just leave it be.

It comes about because the NumPy package [recently deprecated](https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#using-the-aliases-of-builtin-types-like-np-int-is-deprecated) its `numpy.bool` in favour of the standard Python `bool` (or alternatively the awkward `numpy.bool_`), as stated on the documentation page linked in your warning message.

If you can't stand the warning, I suggest you try updating spacepy. You can also [silence the warning explicitly](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) from within your project.

Answer (score 7):

As the other answer notes, it's a warning and generally won't affect anything.
The following code can be used to selectively silence this particular `DeprecationWarning`

```py
from warnings import filterwarnings
filterwarnings(action='ignore', category=DeprecationWarning, message='`np.bool` is a deprecated alias')
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool'.
in 
`>>> import glumpy`