# DeprecationWarning: `np.bool8` is a deprecated alias for `np.bool_`. (Deprecated NumPy 1.24)

Tags: numpy

Can anyone help me to fix this issue
warnings.warn(msg, DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
E   DeprecationWarning: `np.bool8` is a deprecated alias for `np.bool_`.  (Deprecated NumPy 1.24)

[DeprecationWarning: `np.bool`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67779374/deprecationwarning-np-bool)
tried the abov fix but it not worked.

Comment: Are you using `np.bool8` directly in your code?  Or is this warning coming some other package that you are importing?  Your link is from someone using `spacepy`.